# Decide which compatible package to import based on arguments in Python (with inheritance)

Tags: python, inheritance, import, package

I have a PySide2 application, which doesn't run on Spyder due to some issues. However, PyQt5 runs fine. I would like to run the application in Spyder with PyQt5 but outside (console) with PySide2. I don't want to replace packages with search and replace at every deployment/development switch.

Checking with `if 'dev' in sys.argv:` works fine. However, problem is that I have files to be imported with inheritance classes inheriting classes from PySide2/PyQt5. e.g. **Main.py** inherits **Dialog.py**, which has a `class Dialog(QDialog):`. QDialog requires an import but I can't import PySide2 or PyQt5 in that file at that moment. I also can't pass any argument to the imported file afaik.

Is there any way to deal with such issues?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I solved by checking arguments:

```
if 'dev' in sys.argv:
   import PyQt5
else:
   import PySide2
```

Then at every file, where I need to make a similar decision:

```
if 'PySide2' in sys.modules:
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
else:
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    ...
```

When I run the main script with `dev` argument:

```
python main.py dev
```

then it runs with PyQt5, otherwise with PySide2
PS: This also works with **cx_freeze** excluding **PyQt5** package, without any error.